Can't connect to PostgreSQL AWS from LockerStudio
I have an issue with LockerStudio.  I can't add  PostGreSQL ( hosted on AWS) as DataSource.
Current situation:

I am able to connect from my local pgAdmin
Permissions were set up on AWS to grant access to connect from whole internet. All developers across the work doesn't have issues + we are using some software from 3rd party vendors which are working without issues
on locker Studio - I provided correct permissions  and I added certificate:
https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/global/global-bundle.pem. (recommended here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html#UsingWithRDS.SSL.CertificatesAllRegions)

but it shows error:

Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your
request.
Error ID: cb3ff822

Could you please advise me

Are you referring to Looker? It resides on the Internet, so the Postgresql database needs to be accessible from the Internet. When you connect from your "local pgAdmin", do you first need to connect via a VPN, or an SSH jump box, or from your office network? Is the Postgresql database set to Publicly Accessible = Yes? Is the Postgresql database in a public subnet?

Did you resolve the issue to connect the remote postgresql database.I am getting the same error
